# hook_link_alter() and render cache

Tags: theming, 8, caching

I'm using hook_link_alter() to add specific HTML classes based on the current URL.

Unfortunately this no longer works once render cached. Since this is not a render array, the #cache key doesn't seem to do anything.

How would you solve this?

PS: if you know of an alternative to hook_link_alter() which is available in the theme layer, I'm all ears.

Comment: Use JS, like the core does with the "active" class. See \Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGenerator::generate

Comment: I created a core issue to try and fix this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3082473